# saving files on IOS from a Unity 3D game

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

Ok, so I followed the tutorial at unity3d.com (located [here](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/persistence-data-saving-loading))

Just so that you dont have to or want to watch the whole video , here is the save/load functions.

```
//This one saves/creates the file
    void OnDisable()
        {
            BinaryFormatter binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/savedgame.dat");
            GameData data = new GameData();
            data.coinAmount = coinAmount;
            data.upgradeLevel = upgradeLevel;

            binFormatter.Serialize(file, data);
            file.Close();
        }
//And this one loads it 
 void OnEnable()
    {

        if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/savedgame.dat"))
        {
            BinaryFormatter binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/savedgame.dat",FileMode.Open);
            GameData data = (GameData)binFormatter.Deserialize(file) ;
            file.Close();
            coinAmount = data.coinAmount;
            upgradeLevel = data.upgradeLevel;

        }

    }
```

I'm using OnDisable/OnEnable so that my game autosaves every time the users exits. This works on a pc and a mac, but when I build it to the Ipad air2 and its like nothing happens. Xcode trows a exception that says unknown filename(-1).
Thanks in advance for the help
Upon further investigation on android it turns out that the file gets created and the game reads data from it. The problems is here :

```
data.coinAmount = coinAmount;
data.upgradeLevel = upgradeLevel;
```

For some reason this does not write the correct data when  the app runs on Android(probably the same for IOS).
When I supply a hard coded value i.e :   `data.coinAmount = 100;` the game then reads it correctly.

Upon even further investigation turns out that the code work when you call `Application.quit` but does not work when we "force close" the app i.e using the ipads front  button. Need help with this

Comment: Also tested this code on android and again nothing is working. The file is simple not being created . I'm missing some permissions or what ?

Comment: Do you add  Serializable attribute before the class?

Comment: yes, otherwise it wont work on linux mac and windows. It wont work at all.
After more debugging it turns out that I do read the files but for some reason they are not being saved correctly. Now if I change data.coinAmount in the safe function to lets say a static 100 everything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so turns out when we stop a Unity game with the home button on a mobile device the methods OnEnable/OnDisable dont seem to we called or working properly. So my solution to the problem is to migrate the save code to the `OnApplicationPause(bool pauseStatus)` method. After a few tests this seems to be called every time you press the home screen, thus making sure that the game autosaves.

However this only fixed the issue on android devices. Someone please tells me what happens when a IOS user presses the home button so I can freakin save my game when that happens.

Fixed the issue. After some debugging it turns out that ios and .Net JIT do not like each other. This code fixes the issue:

```
if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer)
        {
            System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MONO_REFLECTION_SERIALIZER", "yes");
        }
```

I recommend putting it in the Awake() method.